# Why node js did not work on similar routes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

if i place the get search route on the top then everything works fine if I place the search route at the end then it wont work, Node keep calling the route which takes ID as a parameter, Why this happens and what is the solution for it ?

```
router.get('/search', function (req, res) {

    var p_Where = {};

    if (req.query.IsDeleted)
        p_Where.IsDeleted = req.query.IsDeleted;

    if (req.query.CustomerName)
        p_Where.CustomerName = { $like: '%' + req.query.CustomerName + '%' };

    if (req.query.PhoneNumber)
        p_Where.PhoneNumber = { $like: '%' + req.query.PhoneNumber + '%' };

    if (req.query.OmitCustomerID)
        p_Where.CustomerID = { $ne: req.query.OmitCustomerID };

    if (req.query.CustomerID)
        p_Where.CustomerID = req.query.CustomerID;

    if (req.query.ShowAutoGenerated)
        p_Where.IsAutoGenerated = req.query.ShowAutoGenerated;

    if (req.query.DeviceNumber)
        p_Where.DeviceNumber = req.query.DeviceNumber;

    if (req.query.CarrierID)
        p_Where.CarrierID = req.query.CarrierID;

    console.log(p_Where);
    models.Product.findAll ({
        where : p_Where,
    }).then(function (customer) {
        res.json({
            status : true,
            message : "Products has been found",
            data : customer
        });
    });
});




router.get ('/', function (req, res) {

    models.Product.findAll ({
        where: {
            WholeSaleCustomerId: req.get ("wscId")
        },
        include: [models.ProductSpecification]
    }).then (function (Product) {

        if (Product.length == 0) {
            res.status (404).json ({
                status: false,
                message: "No product has been found."
            });
        }else{
            res.json ({
                status: true,
                message: "Products has been found.",
                data: Product
            });
        }

    });

});



router.get ('/:productId', function (req, res) {
    models.Product.findOne({
        where: {
            WholeSaleCustomerId: req.get ("wscId"),
            id: req.params.productId
        },
        include: [models.ProductSpecification]
    }).then (function (Product) {
        if (!Product) {
            res.status (404).json ({
                status : false,
                message : "No product has been found."
            });
            return;
        }else{
            res.json ({
                status : true,
                message : "Product has been found.",
                data : Product
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `/search` matches `/:productId`. Routes are checked in order, not by how close they match the whole set of routes you declare.

The solution is the one you already use: declare `/search` before `/:productId` (there are some ways around this, but they are hacky).

Comment: Thank you, please explain with some more example it will be very helping for me

Comment: @user2301966 Express doesn't know that you want _"search"_ to be "special" (not meant as a product id) unless you specifically make sure that the `/search` route is matched before `/:productId`.

Answer (score 0):

This breaks because Node recognizes the first matching route and / matches them all. You should give your routes more verbose names like /all and /productById/:id

Comment: Thank you, please explain with some more example it will be very helping for me